# Copy event on IE 11 not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, event-delegation

My case is much more complex, but I was able to reduce it to a simpler one.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdvjks3z/)

It goes like this:

```
<div class="outer" tabindex="0">
      outer div, there are many  child elements herehere
      <div class="inner" tabindex="1">
      at some point, one of those many child has this inner div, it has also multiple child elements showing values. This is the text to copy </div>
</div>
```

I have a div container, say in the example the one which has outer class.
It has many child elements, and one of them is another div, say the one with inner class, which also has lots of child elements.

What I want to achieve is to be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy, while having the focus in the outer div, or in any of its childs.

I tried using copy event in the outer div

```
jQuery('.outer').on('copy', function() {
 // my logic here to access data inside div and copies to clipboard
});
```

and let the event bubble from whatever child is focused when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, so I have only one event registered, and one place in which to execute my logic.

Even though it works fine in Chrome and Firefox, I have some issues with IE11.

In my computer, in which I have installed `IE 11.0.9600.17843` seems to work almost fine (from time to time the event does not fire)

but in another computer with Windows 8.1 and `IE 11.0.9600.18698` fires if I am focused in outer div, but it does not work if I am focused in descendant divs (like in inner for instance).

I've checked that the IE is configured to allow accessing the clipboard programatically in Security section.

From what I understand according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772145(v=vs.85).aspx) is that copy event does not bubble in IE (while it does in FF an Chrome).
Is  that the problem ? How can I fix it ?

The fiddle should work fine in FF and Chrome, but in IE 11 it shouldn't (at least it doesn't for the version mentioned above). I added some CSS so you can know which div is focused to test the problem.

Thanks,

Comment: I've tested jsfiddle on IE11.1000.16188.0 (update version 11.0.41) and all behaviors are identical with Edge and Firefox Developer Edition 55

Comment: the version I say it does not work is update 11.0.43, although the previous mentioned (in W7) seems to be working fine. Is it possible is a bug for that specific version ? So far as I workaround for IE I detect key combinations, but I don't like as a solution

Comment: I think yes. Looks like a bug. Anyway you can submit your problem to https://connect.microsoft.com/ for example or other support resource

Comment: thanks ! I'll do it